# To define an equation of state, does the system need to be in some type of equilbrium?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory, solar-wind

Typically one assumes some sort of equilibrium to define an [equation of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state) for a system.  However, I am curious if equilibrium is actually required to define a general equation of state (with the understanding that it may not be stationary).  The [solar wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind), for instance, is not at all in equilibrium but space plasma physicists still endeavor to find an equation of state for modeling/predictive purposes.

So does the derivation of an equation of state require thermal or thermodynamic equilibrium (or any other type of equilibrium)?

Answer (score 2):

To write down an equation of state, the thermodynamic system has to have well-defined values for all of its *state variables*. This means for example no density gradients, thermal gradients, or changes in the number of particles comprising the system or its volume.

It is not hard to see why. For example, if one end of the system is at temperature T1 and the other end of the system is at T2, which value of the temperature would you plug into the equation of state? So if there are temperature differences between different locations in the system, calculations based on the equation of state will be inconsistent.

Comment: So in your example, would each region with different temperatures have their own equations of state?  That is, must the equation of state be global or can it be local?

Comment: the state variables must have globally-consistent values.

Comment: So perhaps I am misunderstanding, but in Earth's atmosphere we seem to use an equation of state for collisionally mediated shock waves where the density, temperature, and pressure differ across a thin ramp region.  You are saying that is not appropriate or should not be done?